# Using regex get particular value

Tags: java, regex

I have a response like below

```
2020 Aug 05 09:31:25.646515 arrisxg1v4 WPEWebProcess[22024]: [AAMP-PLAYER]NotifyBitRateChangeEvent :: bitrate:2800000 desc:BitrateChanged - Network adaptation width:1280 height:720 fps:25.000000 position:256.000000
```

From this using regex how I can retrieve position value only as Integer. Using java code I can get it using .split method But How I can get this value 256 using Regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this  one-liner:

```
String positionStr = str.replaceAll("(?:(?!position:).)*(?:position:(\\d+))?.*", "$1");
Integer position = positionStr.isEmpty() ? null : new Integer(positionStr);
```

This regex matches the whole string, capturing the target position value in group 1 (`(?:...)` is a non-capturing group), and replaces the match (ie everything) with the captured group. This effectively *deletes* everything you *don't* want.

Conveniently, because the capture is optional (has a quantifier of `?`), if the input does not have a `position:` value, the result is a blank string.

The negative lookahead `(?!position:).` prevents the dot running past our target. Without the negative lookahead, the first dot would consume the  entire input.

Comment: You're missing a closing quote on the first parameter of `replaceAll`

Comment: Also, when I run your solution against the sample line I get an empty String rather than the expected `256`. I'm not sure why though, can't spot any obvious mistakes in the pattern

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*position:(\\d+(\\.\\d+))");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
if (matcher.matches()) {
   String position = matcher.group(1);
}
```

Basically what this expression says is:

- Accept anything up until the word `position`
- Accept a colon `:`
- Accept 1 or more digits (0-9), optionally followed by a dot and 1 or more digits

Then by using `matcher.group` you take everything between parentheses starting at the 1st parenthesis from the left.